# What does a .pipe() function return in gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, npmjs

In the following snippet, what will be the input to and output of  `.pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))` ?

```
gulp.task('useref', function(){
  return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

API docs ([link](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options)) says `.pipe(destination)` returns a reference to the destination stream for setting up chain, if so `.pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))` will return a stream to a minified .js file, how can it be piped to `.pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))` ?

Comment: The stream isn't a minified `.js` file, it's the stream of [Vinyl files](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs) that are being processed -- e.g., the Gulp stream, not a file stream.

Comment: As far as I know, it's a [vinyl](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl) filesystem stream, not just a file.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Good golly, what astounding timing. Question's been here for 14 minutes, and we both comment almost the same thing just *one second* apart?! :-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález @T.J.Crowder good to know that, but the gulp.src()  function seems to return stream of Vinyl files with `.html` extension so why 
is this stream being piped to filter out `*.js` files. Pardon me if I've misunderstood something.

Comment: If that actually works, it's because either `useref()` or `gulpIf()` are doing some magic (for instance, adding new files to the stream). You can find out what package they belong to and read the corresponding docs.

Comment: Is it [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes its almost similiar to the link you provided. Its actually from here https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/#article-header-id-10.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My ISP surely has 1-second lag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp is just a task runner with a rather simple base functionality. Its power comes from the extensive ecosystem of third-party packages, of which your own snippet is using a minimum of four. And I say four because that's what shows up in your *gulpfile.js* source code; gulp itself has [13 direct runtime dependencies](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/package.json):

```
"dependencies": {
    "archy": "^1.0.0",
    "chalk": "^1.0.0",
    "deprecated": "^0.0.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.0",
    "interpret": "^1.0.0",
    "liftoff": "^2.1.0",
    "minimist": "^1.1.0",
    "orchestrator": "^0.3.0",
    "pretty-hrtime": "^1.0.0",
    "semver": "^4.1.0",
    "tildify": "^1.0.0",
    "v8flags": "^2.0.2",
    "vinyl-fs": "^0.3.0"
},
```

... and a similar number of direct development dependencies.

The streams that gulp passes around are provided by [vinyl-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-fs) and do not represent a single file but a virtual file-system.

As about your code, you definitively start only with HTML files:

```
gulp.src('app/*.html')
```

... but right after that you execute a third-party package called [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref):

```
.pipe(useref())
```

As per its docs:

> will parse the build blocks in the HTML, replace them and **pass those
> files through**. Assets inside the build blocks will be concatenated and
> **passed through** in a stream as well.

In other words, it parses the HTML file to identify/generate asset files and it gets them added to the stream for further processing.

Comment: "will parse the build blocks in the HTML" ~ what does it mean? What are build blocks here?

Comment: ah! you meant  `<!-- build:<type> <path> --><!-- endbuild -->` this build block, right ?

Comment: @AlokMishra That's it. But, as I said, that's the specific feature of a given third-party package.